# how to write a query firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I'm trying to filter specific user posts like this:

```
filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(
                        ProfileActivity.this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme
                );
                View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet,
                                (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer)

                        );
                final RadioButton b = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.breakfast);
                final RadioButton dinner = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.dinner);
  if(dinner.isChecked()){

                            Query reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts").orderByChild("Meal");
                            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                    if (snapshot.getValue().equals(dinner.getText().toString()))
                                    {
                                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, dinner.getText() + "is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }
                            });


                        }
```

[image: Here is my database]

I want to check whether the checked `radioButton` value is equal to `Meal` from database, the current code doesn't show the toast message which means the condition is not met even though it is supposed to. How can I write a proper query for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Query reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("Meal");

This will return list of matched data snapshot.
get each snapshot like

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (ds.getValue().equals(dinner.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, dinner.getText() + "is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: this will search for all data of all users, right? I want to apply this for a single user (searching all posts of a single user). I will try your answer and give feedback. thank you

Comment: the for loop is wrong, you mean   for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) ?

Comment: yes but it didn't work. it still doesn't show the toast message

Comment: Try to print `ds.getValue().toString()` and `dinner.getText().toString()` above if statement and debug.

Comment: Thank you it worked but not exactly as I wanted. It searches for all data for all users from the database, I want it to search only for a certain user.

Comment: I don't under stand you app structure so I can't tell that.

Comment: ok thank you.since your answer helped, I will accept it